# im going through a django tutorial im stuck at a place.where my error is OperationalError at / no such table: django_session

Tags: python, django, forms, migration

im trying to make a form im stuck at place the error is opertionalerror .. and many comments was like they told me too migrate ...even if i migrate im getting a error there

[image: cmd page]
my error is[image: error page]
my code part is:
[image: urls.py]
[image: views.py]
[image: base.html]
[image: home.html]

Comment: Please do not post *images* of code, but code itself. Furthermore share the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: run `./manage.py migrate` < you're missing the "/" (or `python manage.py migrate`) < a successful migration will give you the tables needed to run a generic install... ie django_sessions table.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in installed apps i have included my app name also

Comment: @ben thank you much!!! it was useful

Comment: @nivethavenk: that is not the potential problem, the problem is if you installed the Django sessions app.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'halls',
]